# Geometry Node that put objects from collection in line?

Tags: python, geometry-nodes

I have got a task to write python script that creates a geometry node. It takes collection of objects and range of numbers as input. The geometry node is supposed to put all objects from the collection in one line but each object should be multiplied N number of times (N is the randomly generated number from given range). Now, I've never worked with Blender API but so far I got something like this:

[image]

[image]

I've got few questions:

1. In case of more than 2 objects in given collection, how to draw a random count number for each?
2. This geometry node only works with 2 objects. If I wanted to add more I would have to add another Mesh Line, Instance on Points etc. for each object and that would be very impractical. Is there another way?
3. Is there an easier way to do it and how to convert created node to python?

Working geometry node with 4 different meshes creates this monstrosity, but it works. Is there a way to make it simpler, so that it would be easier to convert it to python script? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Please split your questions so that there is always a clear answer to a question if possible. As it is currently worded, this question would be closed, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make Geometry Node on Python. Geometry nodes are written on C++ and you can't mix Custom Python nodes and Geometry Nodes.

But you can build this setup using existing Geometry Nodes:

[image]

[image]

It instances maximum instances from collection, then delete random number in each group. In the final step, it uses accumulate field to shrink the gaps.

[image]